# Content inside layout panel not scrolling

Tags: layout, uwp, scrollview, uwp-xaml

Say I have a simple Windows 10 UWP app

```xml
<Page
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    <!-- etc -->
    >

    <Grid>

        <ListView>
            <TextBlock Text="Sample text"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Sample text"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Sample text"/>
            <!-- & many more -->
        </ListView>

    </Grid>

</Page>
```

The large number of ListView items causes it to overflow and scroll, as expected:

[image]

However, if I need to add another control as a sibling of the ListView, like so (replacing the Grid with a StackPanel for simplicity)

```xml
<Page...>

    <StackPanel>

        <ListView>
            <TextBlock Text="Sample text"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Sample text"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Sample text"/>
            ...
        </ListView>

        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="StackPanel at the bottom"/>
            <Button Content="Click me"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

then the scrollbar disappears and the ListView isn't scrollable anymore. The content just gets clipped / cut off past the bottom of the window.

What's going on here and how can I make it scroll again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this is the [ScrollViewer control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/scroll-controls). The reason ListViews and GridViews can scroll in the first place is because they have a ScrollViewer built in.

When you place a ListView inside a parent layout panel (e.g. a StackPanel or a Grid row), if the ListView height is greater than the viewport, the parent panel becomes the full height of the ListView. But StackPanel doesn't implement ScrollViewer so it can't scroll, and you end up with a StackPanel extending off the bottom edge of the viewport.

The fix is simple: put the parent layout panel in question inside a ScrollViewer

```xml
<Page...>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"> <!--default is "Visible"-->
        <StackPanel>

            <ListView>
                <TextBlock Text="Sample text"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Sample text"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Sample text"/>
                ...
            </ListView>

            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="StackPanel at the bottom"/>
                <Button Content="Click me"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Page>
```

---

[ScrollViewer API reference - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer)

Comment: @CoCaIceDew If I'm answering my own question I normally give it a while before accepting that answer, in case anyone else comes up with something better. But I agree it's now time to accept

Answer (score 1):

Going to add more context to binaryfunt's answer: It depends on the layout logic of the panel you're using!

To note beforehand: `ListView` internally has it's own `ScrollViewer` by default.

When laying out it's children, a `Grid` will typically tell its children they should fit inside the bounds the grid. In the case of the `ListView`, it's happy to do this, and it's own internal `ScrollViewer` handles it's children scrolling.

`StackPanel` on the other hand tells its children they have virtually infinite space to layout in in it's stacking direction - so your `ListView` has no idea it has to constrain itself to the height of your `StackPanel` because the `StackPanel` does not tell it do so and so the ListView never needs to use it's own `ScrollViewer` as it thinks  it has infinite space.

Now, put a `StackPanel` in a `ScrollViewer` by itself doesn't help - if you put that `ScrollViewer` inside a `StackPanel` you have the same problem as the `ListView` does - it thinks it has infinite space and so never needs to scroll it's content. But, put the `ScrollViewer` in a `Grid` and the grid will give the ScrollViewer a defined size to layout in, and so anything inside the `ScrollViewer` will now scroll if it get's too big.

Put a `ListView` inside this `StackPanel` inside this `ScrollViewer`? The `ListView` still thinks it has infinite space and so never needs to use its own scroller, BUT it's also disables and virtualization and performance enhancements the `ListView` would normally have, as they rely on it's interal `ScrollViewer` actually being put a too use.

(binaryfunt's XAML answer will work.)

Comment: Good points! I'm a little confused by the "putting a StackPanel in a ScrollViewer by itself doesn't help" bit though. Are you saying be careful about what the parent of the ScrollViewer is (i.e., if the parent is a StackPanel for example the ScrollViewer won't work)?

Comment: Also, as I understand it, a Grid row behaves differently to a Grid; a Grid row definition with `Height="Auto"` seems to tell its children they have infinite space much like a StackPanel, from what I've tried in solving the problem

Comment: @binaryfunt pretty much - putting a scrollviewer in a stackpanel with default layout options for both makes the ScrollViewer thinks it has infinite space and so doesn't need to actually scroll, because the stackpanel gives it unbounded vertical space to layout in.